# How to flatten two Result

Tags: rust

Given the two functions below, how can I "flatten" the two `Result` into a single one?

```rust
fn result1() -> Result<u8, String> {
  Ok(10)
}

fn result2(number: u8) -> Result<u8, String> {
  Ok(number * 2)
}
```

So, running the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = result1().map(|number| result2(number));
    println!("{:?}", result);
    // Output: Ok(Ok(20))
}
```

I get the same result as this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = result1().map(|number| number * 2);
    println!("{:?}", result);
    // Output: Ok(20)
}
```

Notice the nested Ok `Ok(Ok(20))` instead of the correct single Ok `Ok(20)`.

Something similar to what I'm looking for is the [Rx flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html), but as I'm studying rust I would like to get the job done using the language mindset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`Result::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then):

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = result1().and_then(result2);
    println!("{:?}", result);
    // Output: Ok(20)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not try `and_then` before because its behaviour is completely different from the Rxs `andThen`. That is one nice thing about learning a new language :)